# How does Stack Overflow suggest questions based on title?

Tags: discussion

I am asking how Stack Overflow selects a specific question to depending on the title I wrote in the title header.

I mean depending on what algorithm / mechanism?

Comment: I guess it's a basic words matching + linked questions .. check the related question in the right here and compare the wordings

Comment: that is right, but I need a specific answer as I'm trying to handle it in my website blog

Comment: The [se] developers are unlikely to post their algorithm, and, [se] is closed-source....